# Is there a way to display a vector IN ORDER using a reverse iterator? C++

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

I have this vector of names:

```
vector <string> names;
names.push_back("William");
names.push_back("Maria");
names.push_back("Petterson");
names.push_back("McCarthy");
names.push_back("Jose");
names.push_back("Pedro");
names.push_back("Hang");
```

I need to display this vector IN ORDER using a reverse iterator.

This is my attempt:

```
//Define a reverse iterator for the vector object
vector<string>::reverse_iterator itR = names.rend();

itR = itR - 1;

//Use the reverse iterator to display each element in the vector
cout << "\tNames:\n";
while (itR != names.rbegin())
{
    cout << *itR << endl;
    itR--;
}
```

This will display all names in correct order BUT it cuts off "Hang" at the end, any tips?

Comment: why not just use the forward iterators?

Comment: I'm required to use a reverse iterator for this problem

Comment: Allowed to use https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator/base

Comment: `while(itR != names.rbegin())` means that you don't enter the `while` loop when `itR == names.rbegin()`. But you want to enter it for that case, you just don't want to decrement it and loop again. So you need to rethink how your loop behavior should work.

Comment: among other problems you don't print `rbegin()`: https://godbolt.org/z/hezKrhP68

Comment: This will also crash and burn with an empty vector.

Comment: [**Reverse** iterators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/reverse_iterator) behave a little different than **forward** iterators. Your loop needs to account for that difference.  Reverse iterators aren't typically used in this manner, you should be using forward iterators instead. It doesn't make sense to use reverse iterators to move forwards through a container, that is what forward iterators are meant for.

Comment: Are you sure that your assignment isn't to display the vector elements in *reverse* order? That would be a far more natural usage for reverse iterators.

Comment: The Assignment is : Use a reverse iterator to display the elements of the vector names starting with William.

Comment: That worked Fabian! Thank you so much to everyone!

Comment: @PeteBecker The way I read the question is: The reverse iterator order should be used to print the items in non-reversed order, i.e. the result should be the same as `for (auto& e : names) { std::cout << e << '\n'; }`

Comment: @fabian — oh, I see. The question is completely inside out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you go from the end of a range to the beginning, you should check the equality first and then decrement inside the loop body. Otherwise there either is no iteration for the last element or the iterator gets decremented past the end resulting in undefined behaviour. You could use the following loop:

```
// print elements in original (= non-reversed) order
for (auto pos = names.rend(); pos != names.rbegin();)
{
    --pos;
    std::cout << *pos << std::endl;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The condition of the while statement

```
while (itR != names.rbegin())
```

prevents to output the element of the vector pointed to by the iterator `names.rbegin()`.

Consider for example a vector that contains only one element. In this case after this statement

```
itR = itR - 1;
```

the iterator `itR` will be equal to `names.rbegin()` and the loop will be skipped.

Also it is unclear why you are starting to output the vector starting from the iterator `names.rend() - 1` using the reverse iterator.

Either use original iterators or if you want to output the vector in the reverse order then write

```
//Use the reverse iterator to display each element in the vector
cout << "\tNames:\n";
for ( auto first = names.rbegin(), last = names.rend(); first != last; ++first )
{
    cout << *first << endl;
}
```

Otherwise at least change your code like

```
//Define a reverse iterator for the vector object
vector<string>::reverse_iterator itR = names.rend();

//Use the reverse iterator to display each element in the vector
cout << "\tNames:\n";
while (itR != names.rbegin())
{
    cout << *--itR << endl;
}
```